# Hide UINavigationBar Buttons temporarily

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Is there an easy way to hide the buttons on your UINavigationBar temporarily?

Comment: Have you tried: Nameofbarbutton.alpha = 0.0; ?

Comment: Hmm, have not. Will give it a shot.

Comment: A quick tip: if you want to animate the button and you load the uibarbuttonitem in the -viewDidLoad method with a reference (I.e. uibarbuttonitem * name = ...) then you need to include it in the .h, but don't property or synthesize it.  You just need a reference so that the bar button can be animated from within the .m.

Comment: A UIBarButtonItem doesn't have an alpha property (according to my XCode, anyway)

Comment: Ah!  My bad!  Uibarbuttonitems dont have alpha properties!  Make a blank image and try this: theButton.enabled = NO;
theButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blank.png"];

Answer (score 8):

There are quite a few approaches one can take to hide a `UIBarButtonItem`.  Setting it to nil requires re-instantiation, which is not a pleasant route, so I choose to set it disabled and set a blank image in place of it:

```
self.theButton.enabled = NO;
self.theButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blank.png"];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted this since it isn't wrong. However I haven't upvoted it as it's not complete. As it stands this permanently removes an item from the bar. If you had included comments to re-init it later it would have got an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
button1.width = 0.01;
```

A button to be disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Helps

```
-(void)showBackButton:(BOOL)isShown{
if (isShown) {
    UIBarButtonItem* button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back"
                                                                    style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                   target: self
                                                                   action: @selector(onBack)];
    self.myNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;
    [closeButton release];      
}
else {
    self.myNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all bar buttons on right or left side, use following code

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[];
```

Hope this helps someone.